# Fatal exception of type MWException

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I recently installed MediaWiki in localhost on Debian 7 System. But after the installation, I got the exception `Fatal exception of type MWException`. I reviewed all reported bugs, but they do not apply to me.

PHP 5.4.4
phpmyaddmin....

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug

Comment: Thanks... But I already done this steps... And the issiues persist...

Comment: "`$wgShowExceptionDetails` Enable more details (like a stack trace) to be shown on the "Fatal error" page." We would need to know more than just "Fatal exception of type MWException".

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help... but I believe that was an installation error... I reinstall and  all is function propertly... A lot of thanks...

Answer (score 29):

As written in the comments, edit your `LocalSettings.php` file and add this line at the very end:

`$wgShowExceptionDetails = true;`

Try reloading the page that gives you that error. You're likely to see what's called a backtrace... here is my example:

```
#0 /Users/user/www/extensions/LocalisationUpdate/LocalisationUpdate.class.php(553): LocalisationUpdate::filename('it')
#1 /Users/user/www/extensions/LocalisationUpdate/LocalisationUpdate.class.php(36): LocalisationUpdate::readFile('it')
#2 [internal function]: LocalisationUpdate::onRecache(Object(LocalisationCache), 'it', Array)
#3 /Users/user/www/includes/Hooks.php(255): call_user_func_array('LocalisationUpd...', Array)
#4 /Users/user/www/includes/GlobalFunctions.php(3883): Hooks::run('LocalisationCac...', Array)
#5 /Users/user/www/includes/cache/LocalisationCache.php(796): wfRunHooks('LocalisationCac...', Array)
#6 /Users/user/www/includes/cache/LocalisationCache.php(426): LocalisationCache->recache('it')
#7 /Users/user/www/includes/cache/LocalisationCache.php(310): LocalisationCache->initLanguage('it')
#8 /Users/user/www/includes/cache/LocalisationCache.php(245): LocalisationCache->loadItem('it', 'fallback')
#9 /Users/user/www/languages/Language.php(3978): LocalisationCache->getItem('it', 'fallback')
#10 /Users/user/www/languages/Language.php(230): Language::getFallbacksFor('it')
#11 /Users/user/www/languages/Language.php(189): Language::newFromCode('it')
#12 /Users/user/www/includes/Setup.php(497): Language::factory('it')
#13 /Users/user/www/includes/WebStart.php(161): require_once('/Users/user/3d...')
#14 /Users/user/www/index.php(55): require('/Users/user/3d...')
#15 {main}
```

The first line is the one that stopped the execution, causing the exception. If you can identify the problem (in my case it's the LocalisationUpdate extension) it can be very easy to fix. Again, in my case it's enough to open again `LocalSettings.php` and comment out or delete the line:

```
require_once( "$IP/extensions/LocalisationUpdate/LocalisationUpdate.php" );
```

Answer (score 2):

There could be a problem with caching, try to use

```
$wgMainCacheType = CACHE_NONE;
```